# How to index data from Firebase Firestore to Elastic App Search using Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, elastic-appsearch

I have user generated data in firestore. for full text search feature I am trying to use elastic app search.
I want to deploy Cloud function so whenever a document is written in firestore, a function need to be triggered then the function will index the document.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const axios = require("axios");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.createBPS = functions.firestore
    .document("MyCollection/{docId}")
    .onWrite((snap, context) => {
      axios.post(
          "https://myapp.ent.us-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io/api/as/v1/engines/myengine/documents?auth_token=private-aadsafdsfadsfdsafdafd",
          snap.after.data()
      );
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am developing Mobile App using the following
Flutter
Firebase
Elastic App Search

Sample document in firestore {"id":"1234566", "name": "My name", "description": "My description", etc...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use the offical ES SDK. It would make your code much more stable and easier to read.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/installation.html) is an instruction how to install it and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/update_examples.html) a simple example.